# Searching a ListBox where Items have customised data

Tags: c#, search, listbox

I am loading data into the list box with attached DateTime data. Now I want to search the listbox for an item that contains tagID (eg: e2003450976543). When I search the listbox I cannot find the tagID even though I can see it. I am assuming that the search parameters are not excluding the attached DateTime data. Here is my code:

```
class ExpiringItem
{
    private string text;
    public ExpiringItem(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.Added = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public DateTime Added { get; private set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return text;
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count -1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        var exp = (ExpiringItem)listBox1.Items[i];
        var timeVisible = DateTime.Now - exp.Added;
        if (timeVisible.TotalSeconds > 30)
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);

    }
}
```

To insert I am using: `lstTagsHold.Items.Add(new ExpiringItem(txtTagID.Text));`

Basically all I want to do is check if the `tagID` exists in the listbox or not...

For the test I am using: `if (lstHold.Items.Contains(TagID))..`

Comment: I don't see where you are even checking for the `tagID `..?

Comment: I am using: if (lstHold.Items.Contains(TagID))
                                    {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Items.Contains methos test for **identity** of the param with the object stored in the ListBox.Items. But as you don't have the objects but only a string value it can't work, so you need to **search** through the Items..:

After making `text public` as J.C. has noted, you can access it in a function like this:

```
int findFirstID(ListBox lb, string id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var ei = lb.Items[i] as ExpiringItem;
        // if text is public:
        if (ei.text == id) return i;
        // if it isn't:
        if (ei.ToString()== id) return i;

    }
    return -1;
}
```

This will return the index of the first item with the ID you search for or -1 if it is not found.

If all you want is to check if is is in the `listBox` you can use a little `LINQ`:

```
// if text is public:
if (listBox1.Items.Cast<ExpiringItem>().Where(x => x.text == yourID).Count() > 0) ..

// if it isn't::
if (listBox1.Items.Cast<ExpiringItem>().Where(x => x.ToString()== yourID).Count() > 0) ..
```

Comment: I think I'm having a blonde moment or whole day. This is the error I get: Error 26 'MT.Compcrete.frmMain.ExpiringItem.text' is inaccessible due to its protection level G:\Current Software Dev\1 AT Race Timing System\22A 07.15 Standalone\Client\frmMain.cs 1577 90 Client
How can I make it public and accessable?

Comment: As has been noted in two answers and the error msg: you need to make the text field puvlic one way ot another or you can't access it from outside. __Or__ you can change the code to use the `ToString()` method you already have. I'll change the answer..

Comment: Okay, so I have changed properties to this: public string text;. and then run this code: if (listBox1.Items.Cast<ExpiringItem>().Where(x => x.text == TagID).Count() > 0)
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Item found");
                                    }

Comment: But it says unable to cast object of type "System.String to type 'ExpiringItem'

Comment: Sorted. I got it running. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the tagID is equal to `this.text` in your code.

You need to know that ListBox does not contain a list of string, but a list of objects. You can see the tagID because you have override the ToString() method to present the text.

And according to `var exp = (ExpiringItem)listBox1.Items[i];` , the exp.text should be your tagID, but it's **private**. Please write a public property for it, and your tagID is there.

Comment: I have tried: string serTag = (ExpiringItem)listBox1.Items[g].ToString(); but this gives errors

Comment: How about `string serTag = ( (ExpiringItem)listBox1.Items[g] ).ToString();` ?